# org.omg.stub.java.rmi._Remote_Stub incompatibility

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

I'm following this guide http://jonas.ow2.org/doc/JONAS_5_1_7/doc/doc-en/html/ejb3_programmer_guide.html in order to learn how write the EJB 3.0, but I'm stuck after the chapter `2.3. Writing the Client Code`.

I'm using RAD 8.5 with WAS 7.0. 
I created the EJB project and the session bean, but when I run the client (that is in the same project and EAR of the bean) I always get this error:

```
22-lug-2014 12.33.15 null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
22-lug-2014 12.33.15 null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
22-lug-2014 12.33.15 null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
22-lug-2014 12.33.15 null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
22-lug-2014 12.33.15 null null
INFO: Client code attempting to load security configuration
Exception in thread "P=194786:O=0:CT" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.omg.stub.java.rmi._Remote_Stub incompatible with HelloWorldInterface
    at Client.main(Client.java:26)
```

I've tried several solutions, but without results. 
Any idea about how to solve the error?

Comment: Try it with `PortableObject.narrow()`. I'm not convinced that you don't need it.

Comment: Then you for helping me. I've already tried, but didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In java main or JUnit context you must have EJB 3 stubs generated using createEJBStubs.bat. I'm using ANT task to generate it for me ...

was.home - root directory of WAS installation

locationName - location of the EAR file

```
<target name="export_ear">
    <earExport earProjectName="MyProject" earExportFile="${locationName}/MyProject.ear" exportSource="false" overwrite="true"/> 
</target>

<target name="createStubs" depends="export_ear">
    <exec executable="${was.home}/bin/createEJBStubs.bat">
        <arg line="${locationName}/MyProject.ear" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

After you generated stubs, you have to extract MyProject.jar and MyProjectClient.jar from MyProject.ear and include them to your build path.